# NestJS-How to access get method of EasyconfigService in my config file

Tags: nestjs, environment

Added EasyconfigModule in my app module,

```
import  { Module }  from  '@nestjs/common';
import { EasyconfigModule } from  'nestjs-easyconfig';

@Module({
imports:  [EasyconfigModule.register({path: './config/.env'})],
})
export  class  AppModule  {}
```

and created a `.env` file with

```
USERNAME= abcd 
PASSWORD= abcd
```

And I need to access the get method of `easyconfigService` in my `config.ts` file. It shows

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

How to solve this issue?

`config.ts` file:

```
import { EasyconfigService } from 'nestjs-easyconfig';
let easyconfigService: EasyconfigService
export const config: ConfigOptions = {
username: easyconfigService.get('USERNAME'),
password: easyconfigService.get('PASSWORD'),
}
```

Comment: you will have to inject the service, inside the easyconfigService through the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this

```
import { EasyconfigService } from 'nestjs-easyconfig';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor (private config: EasyconfigService) {}
  findAll() {
    return {
      username: this.config.get('USERNAME'),
      password: this.config.get('PASSWORD')
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any method to inject service in a file without constructor,because my ts file contains export constant only.